# How to write a nested search the Ruby way?

Tags: ruby, coding-style

I am trying to write fast and concise code. I'd appreciate your thoughts on which is the best way to write the following code and why:

Option #1

```
def get_title
  title = check_in_place_one
  if title.empty?
    title = check_in_place_two
    if title.empty?
      title = check_in_place_three
    end
  end
  return title
end
```

Option #2

```
def get_title
  title = check_in_place_one
  title = check_in_place_two unless !title.empty?
  title = check_in_place_three unless !title.empty?
  return title
end
```

I think Option #1 is better since if the `title` is found by `check_in_place_one`, we test `title.empty?` once and then skip the rest of the code in the method and return. But, it looks too long. Option #2 appears better, but processes `title.empty?` one extra time, and unnecessary time before returning. Also, am I missing a third option?

Comment: Besides your main point, double negation `unless !...` is bad, both from readability and performance.

Comment: @sawa from a readability perspective or another reason?

Comment: @izmangyo Mostly readability. `unless !...` is a double-negative. `if ...` is better.

Comment: Are the `check_in_place...` methods or variables? While it's OK to not use parenthesis with a method, it's hard to tell in your code.

Comment: @theTinMan check_in_place.. are methods. They don't take any params because they all work on a common instance variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From performance, there is no difference between the two versions of your code (besides very minor difference that may come from parsing, which should be ignorable). The control structures are the same.

From readability, if you can get away with nesting, doing so is better. Your second option is better.

It is usually better to get rid of any case that does not need further processing. That is done by `return`.

```
def get_title
  title = check_in_place_one
  return title unless title.empty?
  title = check_in_place_two
  return title unless title.empty?
  title = check_in_place_three
  return title
end
```

The last `title =` and `return` in the code above are redundant, but I put them there for consistency, which improves readability.

You can further compact the code using `tap` like this:

```
def get_title
  check_in_place_one.tap{|s| return s unless s.empty?}
  check_in_place_two.tap{|s| return s unless s.empty?}
  check_in_place_three
end
```

`tap` is a pretty much fast method, and unlike `instance_eval`, its performance penalty is usually ignorable.

Comment: I didn't know about `tap`. From what I'm reading, it seems that it's useful for doing something with the intermediate results of a method chain. But it looks like you're using it purely for compactness. Is that right? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The following approach could be used for any number of sequential tests.  Moreover, it is completely general.  The return condition could be changed, arguments could easily be assigned to the test methods, etc.

```
tests = %w[check_in_place_one check_in_place_two check_in_place_three]

def do_tests(tests)
  title = nil # Define title outside block
  tests.each do |t|
    title = send(t)
    break unless title.empty?
  end
  title
end
```

Let's try it:

```
def check_in_place_one
  puts "check 1"
  []
end

def check_in_place_two
  puts "check 2"
  ''
end

def check_in_place_three
  puts "check 3"
  [3]
end

do_tests(tests) #=> [3]
check 1
check 2
check 3
  #=> [3]
```

Now change one of the tests:

```
def check_in_place_two
  puts "check 2"
  'cat'
end

do_tests(tests) #=> 'cat'
check 1
check 2
  #=> "cat"
```

If there were more tests, it might be convenient to put them in a module which would be `include`d into a class. Mixed-in methods behave the same as those that you define for the class.  For example, they have access to instance variables.  I will demonstrate that with the definition of the first test method.  We probably want to make the test methods private.  We could do it like this:

```
module TestMethods
  private

  def check_in_place_one
    puts "@pet => #{@pet}"
    puts "check 1"
    []
  end

  def check_in_place_two
    puts "check 2"
    ''
  end

  def check_in_place_three
    puts "check 3"
    [3]
  end
end

class MyClass  
  @@tests = TestMethods.private_instance_methods(false)
  puts "@@tests = #{@@tests}"

  def initialize
    @pet = 'dog'
  end

  def do_tests
    title = nil # Define title outside block
    @@tests.each do |t|
      title = send(t)
      break unless title.empty?
    end
    title
  end   

  include TestMethods       
end
```

The following is displayed when the code is parsed:

```
@@tests = [:check_in_place_one, :check_in_place_two, :check_in_place_three]
```

Now we perform the tests:

```
MyClass.new.do_tests #=> [3]
@pet => dog
check 1
check 2
check 3
```

Confirm the test methods are private:

```
MyClass.new.check_in_place_one
  #=> private method 'check_in_place_one' called for...'
```

The advantage of using a module is that you can add, delete, rearrange and rename the test methods without making any changes to the class.

Comment: I had my "test methods" as private methods in my class, but I was feeling like they were getting out of hand. I like the suggestion of putting them in a separate module, but if I do that and include the module in the class (like your code above shows), would they still have access to the instance variables of the class? thanks!

Comment: iz, I did an edit to address your question and also show how the test methods can be made private.  Feel free to ask additional questions or suggest improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's a few other alternatives.

**Option 1:** Return first non-empty check.

```
def get_title
  return check_in_place_one   unless check_in_place_one.empty?
  return check_in_place_two   unless check_in_place_two.empty?
  return check_in_place_three
end
```

**Option 2:** Helper method with short-circuit evaluation.

```
def get_title
  check_place("one") || check_place("two") || check_place("three")
end

private

def check_place(place)
  result = send("check_in_place_#{place}")
  result.empty? ? nil : result
end
```

**Option 3:** Check all places then find the first that's non-empty.

```
def get_title
  [
    check_in_place_one,
    check_in_place_two,
    check_in_place_three,
  ].find{|x| !x.empty? }
end
```

Comment: In option 1, you're calling each method at least twice so it's not an optimal alternative. Option 2 is good and gets the point across in one line. Option 3 could be shortened by replacing the .find method and block with just .compact assuming those check methods will return nils and not empty strings but it still calls all the methods always without short circuiting like option 2 would. So, your option 2 is the shortest and most optimal.

Comment: @diego.greyrobot Calling each method twice may or may not be a problem depending on exactly what those methods are. If they're just plain old getter methods it shouldn't be a problem. Oh, and the check methods do return empty strings; that's the problem. Otherwise option 2 would work fine without the helper method.

Comment: @ajedi32 Option 2 could work for my situation. The methods do complex things and return empty arrays if unsuccessful, so I would not want to call them twice. I wasn't aware of the `send` method. If I do as Cary Swoveland suggested above and store these methods in a separate Module and include them in my Class, will your helper method with `send` still work as above? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 looks good although you did a 360 degree turn with the `unless !title.empty?`. You can shorten that to `if title.empty?` since `unless` is equivalent to an `if !` so doing an `unless !` takes you back to just `if`.

If you're only ever going to have 3 places to look in then option 2 is the best. It's short, concise, and easy to read (easier once you fix the aforementioned whoopsie). If you might add on to the places you look for a title in you can get a bit more dynamic:

```
def get_title(num_places = 4)
  title, cur_place = nil, 0
  title = check_in_place(cur_place += 1) while title.nil? && cur_place < num_places
end

def check_in_place(place_num)
  # some code to check in the place # given by place_num
end
```

The tricky line is that one with the `while` in it. What's happening is that the `while` will check the expression `title.nil? && cur_place < num_places` and return true because the `title` is still nil and 0 is less than 4.

Then we'll call the `check_in_place` method and pass in a value of 1 because the `cur_place += 1` expression will increment its value to 1 and then return it, giving it to the method (assuming we want to start checking in place 1, of course).

This will repeat until either `check_in_place` returns a non nil value, or we run out of places to check.

Now the `get_title` method is shorter and will automatically support checking in `num_places` places given that your `check_in_place` method can also look in more places.

One more thing, you might like to give https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ a look, this question seems like it'd be a good fit for it.

Comment: This could work for a situation slightly different than mine. In my case, it is important to have the actual names of the methods in the code because they are descriptive and explain to the code reader exactly what is being checked. Thanks for explaining my gaff with `unless` and for recommending the Code Review site -- it looks great for my needs!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any reason to get too clever:

```
def get_title
  check_in_place_one || check_in_place_two || check_in_place_three
end
```

Edit: if the check_in_place_X methods are indeed returning an empty string on failure it would be better (and more idiomatic) to have them instead return `nil`. Not only does it allow for truthy comparisons like the above code, `return ""` results in the construction of a new and unnecessary String object.

Comment: This won't work. The fact that the OP is calling `.empty?` on the returned values implies that they return empty strings, not nil, when no value is found. And `!!"" == true`